# completely remove reference from reference list

Tags: excel, vba

I need to remove a reference from the list of references under tools/references. Not just uncheck it, completely remove it from the list.

I am trying to load another reference (a DLL) with the same name but I cannot, I suspect that is because there is already a DLL by that name in the list. Changing the file name of the new DLL does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the regsvr32 command in an administrator command line prompt

```
regsvr32 dllfile.dll
```

This command will replace the existing reference in excel visual basic to a file of the same name with the file passed to regsvr32.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually what I use when removing references, this also gives the method for adding your new reference path.

```
Sub RemoveRefs()

Dim RefPath As String, X As Long
Const RefName = "Your Reference's Name"
YourNewRefPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\dsofile.dll"

With ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References
    For X = 1 To .Count
        If .Item(X).Description Like RefName Then
            .Remove .Item(X)
        End If
Next
.AddFromFile (YourNewRefPath)

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I did something like this and all it did was uncheck the reference